# extraer sublista pareada de forma condicional de una lista de strings (en R)

Tags: r, lista, substring, tidyverse

Me hallo extrayendo los datos de una vieja caja registradora. Está contiende registros de los tickets de venta en un formato obsoleto del cual no tengo la llave y me hallo extrayendo la información que contiene en formato `string`. Cada archivo de la corresponde a un día , puedo cargarlo y leerlo en `R` con `read_csv`.

A continuación un ejemplo del output de un archivo:

```
[1] "<21-01-20 22:30002437/1      25.70   :10011001006520-"
[2] "A 1010 ARTICULO 1             1     10.00         1110       0   0       0.004920."
[3] "A 1014 ARTICULO 2             1      9.50         1110       0   0       0.00FA20/"
[4] "A  202 ARTICULO 3             1      2.50         0110       0   0       0.006C200"
[5] "A  202 ARTICULO 3             1      2.50         0110       0   0       0.006C201"
[6] "A    3 ARTICULO 4             1      1.20         0110       0   0       0.00F4202"
[7] "R    2 TARJETA                1     25.7041203"
[8] "h   92 MODIFICAR COBRO        1       0.009A204"
[9] "x    1 I.V.A. 10%             1      2.34      1000    23.36 08205"
[10]"c    0                         0       0.00           -        08F206"
[11]"B    3 AT         ->     2437           76207"
[12]"-D    0  -1  1127     1F1208"
[13]"\21-01-20 21:11002435/1      13.00   :51007001002520{"
[14]"A 1052 ARTICULO 5              1      12.00         1110       0   0       0.002720|"
[15]"A   80 ARTICULO 6              1       1.00         0110       0   0       0.002620}"
[16]"R    1 EFECTIU                 1      13.008220~"
[17]"x    1 I.V.A. 10%              1       1.18      1000     11.82 4220"
[18]"c    0                         0       0.00           -        08F20 "
[19]"-D    0   1  1127     1B220!"
[20]"<21-01-20 22:30002439/1      25.70   :5901000100C720C"
[21]"/21-01-2020 22:55/4/127/01085775/17/4E20D"
```

El output final que busco de esa lista sería:

```
$`21-01-20 22:30`
  Codigo_producto Nombre_articulo Cantidad Precio
1            1010      ARTICULO 1        1   10.00
2            1014      ARTICULO 2        1    9.50
3             202      ARTICULO 3        1    2.50
4             202      ARTICULO 3        1    2.50
5               3      ARTICULO 4        1    1.20
$`21-01-20 21:11`
  Codigo Nombre_articulo Cantidad Precio
1   1052      ARTICULO 5        1     12.0
2     80      ARTICULO 6        1      1.0
```

- El primer elemento de la lista correspondería al contenido de las líneas entre 2 y 6, con nombre de lista la fecha contenida en la línea 1.
- El segundo elemento de la lista correspondería a las líneas entre 14 y 15, con nombre de lista la fecha contenida en la línea 13.

Mi problema no está en las expresiones regulares para la extracción individual de los artículos. Ya he creado las expresiones expresiones regulares para la extracción de los elementos cuyo string comienza por la letra **A**. **Mi problema es no sé como conseguir que la fecha y los artículos que cuadren de forma en el resultado final.**

Necesito coger solo las fechas de las líneas cuyo línea siguiente que comience por `A`. He probado con substrings de varios tipos, pero no domino esto de trabajar con listas en formato condicional. Además hay ciertas limitaciones:

- Las fechas a veces puede aparecer con el símbolo **\** o bien el símbolo **<** (como se pueden ver en las filas 1 y 13).
- A veces aparecen fechas que no contienen nada relacionado con una compra como en las filas 20 y 21.

Normalmente uso el formato de programación funcional `tidyverse` en `R`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sé si es una solución completa, pero resuelve buena parte de los problemas. Le falta regex para extraer las fechas y una mejor separación de las columnas, eso deberías testearlo con tus datos completos.

Va comentado en la línea anterior.

```
library(tidyverse)

#crudo es el vector de caracteres tomado del ejemplo de output. Lo paso a un data.frame.
enframe(crudo) |> 
#Detecto las fechas, crea un columna que TRUE cuando fecha y FALSE cuando no
  mutate(serie = str_detect(crudo, "[0-9]\\-[0-9]")) |> 
#Con la suma acumulada identifico cada serie de datos (evento de compra), TRUE es 1, FALSE es 0
  mutate(acum = cumsum(serie)) |> 
#Agrupo por evento de compra
  group_by(acum |> 
#Para cada evento extraigo la primera fila, es la fecha
  mutate(fecha = value[1]) |> 
#Y después la elimino, ya está en otra parte.
  slice(-1) |> 
#Me quedo con los que empiezan con A, artículos.
  filter(str_detect(value, "^A")) |> 
#Y los separo en sus partes. Esto depende de posiciones fijas, es código peligroso.
  separate(value, into = c("id", "código", "artículo", 
                           "otro_de_artículo", "cantidad", "precio")) |> 
#Me quedo con las variables que me interesan, tubería de dplyr pq con la nativa de R no anda el truquito de split.
  select(código:precio, fecha) %>% 
#Como las fechas se repiten a lo largo del evento puedo usarlas para separar en la lista.
  split(.$fecha)
```

Resultado

No es exacto lo que buscas, le faltaría trabajar con regex para extraer la fecha (idealmente hacerlo antes del split, pero avanza bastante.

```
Adding missing grouping variables: `acum`
$`\021-01-20 21:11002435/1      13.00   :51007001002520{`
# A tibble: 2 × 7
# Groups:   foo [1]
    foo código artículo otro_de_artículo cantidad precio fecha                                    
  <int> <chr>  <chr>    <chr>            <chr>    <chr>  <chr>                                    
1     2 1052   ARTICULO 5                1        12     "\u0011-01-20 21:11002435/1      13.00  …
2     2 80     ARTICULO 6                1        1      "\u0011-01-20 21:11002435/1      13.00  …

$`<21-01-20 22:30002437/1      25.70   :10011001006520-`
# A tibble: 5 × 7
# Groups:   foo [1]
    foo código artículo otro_de_artículo cantidad precio fecha                                    
  <int> <chr>  <chr>    <chr>            <chr>    <chr>  <chr>                                    
1     1 1010   ARTICULO 1                1        10     <21-01-20 22:30002437/1      25.70   :10…
2     1 1014   ARTICULO 2                1        9      <21-01-20 22:30002437/1      25.70   :10…
3     1 202    ARTICULO 3                1        2      <21-01-20 22:30002437/1      25.70   :10…
4     1 202    ARTICULO 3                1        2      <21-01-20 22:30002437/1      25.70   :10…
```

Comment: Bravo por la parte del primer mutate para tener una variable auxiliar que permite tener un contador acumulado. Era justo lo que necesitaba para tener los grupos de listas separados. Me sirve no solo para este, sino para varios problemas que tengo en marcha. Mil gracias